# Inserting variables when using HEREDOC?

Tags: php, api, heredoc

I'm making an API call to an email marketing service. One of the variables is "htmlContent" that has the HTML of the email to be sent.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
$htmlContent = <<<EOT
//lots of HTML code
<p>
EOT;

$htmlContent .= $player_name;

$htmlContent .= <<<EOT
</p>
//lots more HTML code
EOT;
```

I'm trying to insert the $player_name variable directly in between the `<p></p>` tags. When I add in this variable, my API call breaks. If I remove the variable addition, it works fine. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Is $player_name set already?

Comment: Yep, it is. Before adding the HTML template, I simply outputted that value to the "htmlContent" and I received the email with the correct variable output.

Comment: What do you mean "my API call breaks"? PHP doesn't know you're making an API call, and the API doesn't know what your PHP code looks like. So forget the API for a moment, and dump out the exact string you're generating in the two versions. Compare them carefully - is there a whitespace difference perhaps, or just something in the `$player_name` variable that will mess up the wider format?

Comment: Nope, $player_name looks good. To take it a step further, I replaced $player_name with "Test Player" to eliminate the variable aspect. Even this doesn't work.. Is there some sort of syntax issue with appending to variables that contain EOT content? When I eliminate appending using .= and just put all HTML content into 1 variable at one time, it works fine.

Comment: To clarify, when I say "the API call breaks", it means I don't receive the email from the API call I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out I don't even need to break the EOT to enter the variable, I can just add `{$player_name}` directly in to the EOT code. Who would've known I was overcomplicating it...